# How to use stub.CreateTable in Hyperledger programming

Tags: go, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, smartcontracts

A chaincode based on Hyperledger uses stub.PutState and stub.GetState to interact with the data base. However, if I have a struct with more than one attibutes, for example :

`person {
   "ID": "123",
   "firstname":"joe",
   "lastname":"doe",
   "age":"34",
}`

Then if I want to update the age, what arguments should I send to the method ?

I noticed that there is stub.CreateTable method which seems to be more convenient for my case, however, I couldn't find any document or explication about how to use this method. Would you please give me a link to the document or some brief explication please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change anything on the ledger.The only way you can update the person infomation is insert a new line to cover the old.

Comment: TristeShine is not asking for changing the data in the ledger. User just wants to see the updated age values when he/she queries for data. As long as the age column is not a key attribute, they can use the replaceRow API Fabric has provided. This API do not overwrite the existing data, rather creates link to the new value of age. So when TristeShine uses selection API from Fabric smart contract, fabric would show the data (rows) with updated values of age. So while you are write fundamentally that you can not change anything, but it's possible to create the perception of update operation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a chaincode where a table is used. You can see how to create a table, insert, delete rows : 
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/examples/chaincode/go/asset_management_interactive/asset_management.go#L51-L54

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the cases in the switch statement in the `invoke` method of this code. I believe the `case "replaceRowTableOne":` case has some insight as to what you're trying to do.

https://github.com/christo4ferris/fabric-docs/blob/master/bddtests/chaincode/go/table/table.go